# set mdraws range using stata

Tags: set, range, stata

I am using the Stata command `mdraws` to generate random numbers (by default using Halton sequences).

I am wondering if there's a way to set the range for the random numbers? For example, is there anything I could do using `mdraws` if I want my random numbers to be in the range of 0.05 to 0.5?

Answer (score 2):

Elsewhere in the Stata community you are asked to explain where user-written commands you use come from, and that is a very good convention also for Stack Overflow.

`mdraws` is a program by Capellari and Jenkins from *Stata Journal* 6(2), 2006: readers will find that typing `findit mdraws` in Stata produces pointers to download sources.

The direct answer is No, but the problem is easily tackled by rescaling. For any variable `x` generated in the interval from 0 to 1, map to 0.05 to 0.5 by

```
   gen x = 0.05 + 0.45 * y
```

If you have several such variables, use `foreach` or `forval` in a loop to rescale.

You didn't spell it out, so I will: this presumes that you want densities uniform on your stated interval.